# Alternating polynomial of even degree is always greater than 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Is it true that 
$$x^{2k} - x^{2k-1} + x^{2k-2} + .... + x^2 - x \geq 0$$
for any $x$ real, and $k\geq 3$ a positive integer?
It seems to be true for $k\geq 3$, but it is not true for k=2. I thought about grouping the terms two by two but I didn't have much success.

Edit: Nevermind it obviously fails for x in $(0,1)$. Ignore the question.

Edit 2: Actually, it seems that 
$$x^{2k} - x^{2k-1} + x^{2k-2} + .... + x^2 - x + 1 \geq 0$$
for all positive integers $k$. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: You can delete the question if you wish

Comment: $$x\cdot \frac{x^{2k}-1}{x+1} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Unless $x=-1$, your expression is equal to$$\frac{x^{2k+1}-x}{x+1}.$$

Comment: Is it irreducible?

Comment: No, since it is a multiple of $x$.